# Insert Description with Line Breaks via YouTube Data API

Tags: swift, youtube

I have working code that uploads my video, title and description to YouTube using Swift and Alamofire.

My description uploads to YouTube as one line and I would like to split the line to break after each variable.

My description variable is like so:

```
 myDescription = (price! as! String) + " " + (package! as! String)
```

When that get's sent to YouTube, it appears as:

"Pricehere PackageName"

I want the PackageName to show in the YouTube description with a line break like:

"Pricehere
PackageName"

I had done this in Objective C on an old project like this:

```
     NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@", str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6];
```

When that was passed to YouTube it added each variable and then did a line break.

Thanks for any help.

*edit* adding in the function for the YouTube Upload for reference:

```
 func postVideoToYouTube(token: String, callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
    let urlYoutube = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet"

    let path = videoURL?.path
    let videodata: Data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!)! as! Data

    upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append("{'snippet':{'title' : '\(self.myTitle)', 'description': '\(self.myDescription)'}}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "snippet", mimeType: "application/json")
            multipartFormData.append(videodata, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
    },
        to: urlYoutube,
        method:Alamofire.HTTPMethod.post,
        headers:headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                    let result = response.result.value
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                    let videoId = JSON.object(forKey: "id") as! String
                    print("VideoID: ", videoId)
                    self.addVideoToPlaylist(videoId: videoId, callback: { (result) in
                        callback(result)
                    })

                }
                break
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                callback(false)
                break
            }

    }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with force casting variables like you're doing, I would recommend you to do something like this:

```
if let price = price as? String, let package = package as? String {
    myDescription = "\(price)\n\(package)"
}
```

This way you're safe unwraping and also using String Interpolation to construct the string, you can read more in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

Comment: I tried your code and it crashes the upload code at  "let videoId = JSON.object(forKey: "id") as! String" if I use the \n.  If I take it out and leave a space it runs fine (but all items still on one line obviously).

Comment: It ended up being \\n between the two swift variables.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.